# How does the conversion of torrent to direct link work?

Tags: links, download

I know there are lots of sites that convert torrent links to IDM or a direct link.

I am interested in how that conversion works.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of [websites](http://www.webrevud.com/download-torrent-files-using-idm/) simply download the torrent for you, and cache the downloaded file(s) on their servers so that you can access it directly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Server have a torrent client installed that downloads the torrent requested and generate a download link.
Some Sites(*Furk.net?*) keeps the data downloaded on their servers to avoid wasting unnecessary bandwidth to re-download popular torrents.